# Data pointers? Shifting one array seems to affect another

Tags: javascript, arrays, pointers, memory, async.js

When I shift the tempArr, async.eachSeries will actually skip coordinates (or it seems like coordinatesArr is getting shifted as well). I think it has to do with the pointers pointing to objects with the same memory location, but I have no concept of how that works. What is actually happening when I assign values to variables?

The code will work if I do

```js
tempArr = _.toArray(coordinates);
```

instead of

```js
tempArr = coordinatesArr;
```

Sample below:

```js
   

 var coordinatesArr, tempArr;
    var marginLon = [];
    var marginLat = [];
    var coordinates = { 
     '0': { lon: 13.18472, lat: 32.88972 },
     '1': { lon: 13.400454, lat: 32.767144 },
     '2': { lon: -120.59234, lat: 47.372269 },
     '3': { lon: 122.065977, lat: -26.471618 },
     '4': { lon: 122, lat: -25 } 
    }

    coordinatesArr = _.toArray(coordinates);
    tempArr = coordinatesArr;
    // Will work if changed to below
    // tempArr = _.toArray(coordinates);

    async.eachSeries(coordinatesArr, function(set, acb) {
     tempArr.shift();
     if(tempArr.length < 1) return acb();
     async.eachSeries(tempArr, function(set2, aacb) {
      marginLon.push(Math.abs(set.lon - set2.lon));
      marginLat.push(Math.abs(set.lat - set2.lat));
      aacb();
     }, function(err) {
      if(err) return acb();
      acb();
     });
    }, function(err) {
     if(err) return;
     return;
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `_.toArray()`? What is the purpose of calling `.shift()`?

Comment: _.toArray() is from the lodash library that converts objects into an array. What I am trying to do is an asynchronous nested for loop. The purpose of the shift is so I don't compare the same coordinates (ie coordinates[0] with coordinates[0].

Answer (score 0):

All variables can ultimately only contain scalar (non-compound) values. However some of those values are simply references objects (e.g. pointers to object or array). You must recognize when you need a copy of the data that you can modify while retaining the original.

first question why don't you start with an array?

```
var coordinatesArr = [ 
  { lon: 13.18472, lat: 32.88972 },
  { lon: 13.400454, lat: 32.767144 } // etcetera
]
```

secondly, shift is a destructive operation, if tempArr and coordinatesArr both point to the same physical array, modifying one modifies both.

You need something like the line below to create a modifiable array that doesn't harm the orginal:

```
var tempArr = coordinatesArr.slice();
```

Comment: 1. I pulled this section out of a bigger script. That's the response I get when I hit a third party api.  

2. I think I get it now, so when I declare a variable, I am really just creating pointers to locations in memory unless that object is being created.

By doing 
`var tempArr = coordinatesArr.slice();`
Do I now have 2 arrays in memory?

Comment: Yes you now have two arrays. One you can rely on as a record of what you started with until you no longer need it, the other which can be shrunk or modified.